# Bending in hyperbolic geometry

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Bending of a surface conserves parallelism between any two initially parallel geodesic lines.

Can some examples be given from hyperbolic geometry ? How are bent surface hyperbolic geodesic parallel lines understood in the three models?

Comment: What is the meaning of "straight lines"? Does this not mean geodesics? Horocycles are most definitely not "straight lines."

Comment: Thanks, shall change it to what I mean.